# What does the ^ sign actually do?

Tags: python

Hi I'm just starting python and my teacher isn't great at explaining everything so I'm still not quite sure how ""7^2"" is equals to 5?

Comment: this has a great explanation too of the "bitwise operators" https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: Think of it as `0b111 ^ 0b010 == 0b101`.  (And if those `0b` numbers don't look familiar to you, try entering them at the REPL and see what they equate to!)  The XOR operator puts a 1 in every place where it's *different* in the two operands.